# fade in text left to right or vice-versa

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know how to make the text appear as the div floating_mask grows.
right now the text while growing the div the text is put in two lines when the translation ends as the div is already at 100% if it stays as it has to be.

```css
.floating {

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .container {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .mask {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    height: 54px;
    width: 54px;
    transition: width 1s;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateX(2px);
  }
  
   .button:hover + .mask{
      width: 200px;
   }

  .button {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    z-index: 2;
    top:17px;
    left:17px;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="floating">
    <button type="button"  class="button ">
       Icon
    </button>
    <div class="mask">
        <div class="container">
            <p style="margin: 0;font-size:14px">Message group</p>
             <p style="margin: 0;font-size:14px">Message group</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css :

```css
.container {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: floatText 5s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  }
```

Here is fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/15n3quaL/

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is using `&nbsp;` in between words.

```css
.floating {

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .container {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .mask {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    height: 54px;
    width: 54px;
    transition: width 1s;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateX(2px);
  }
  
   .button:hover + .mask{
      width: 200px;
   }

  .button {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    z-index: 2;
    top:17px;
    left:17px;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="floating">
    <button type="button"  class="button ">
       Icon
    </button>
    <div class="mask">
        <div class="container">
            <p style="margin: 0;font-size:14px">Message&nbsp;group</p>
             <p style="margin: 0;font-size:14px">Message&nbsp;group</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```